# unable to fetch records from sql to pandas using pd.read_sql_table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-python

```py
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    port =3306,
    password = "Veera@123",
    database = 'sql_prac',
    auth_plugin = 'mysql_native_password'
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

able to fetch data using pd.read_sql() and pd.read_sql_query() but unable to fetch using pd.read_sql_table

```py
pd.read_sql_table("dummy1",con=mydb)
```

showing error like below

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: It seems you're mixing a lot of databases, your server looks like mysql, but the error looks like sqlite, finally you also tagged sql server for some reason

Comment: I've removed the [[tag:sql-server]] tag, as it's clearly unrelated.